# Flask - file upload - Method Not Allowed

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to create an upload file with flask - but keep getting the error `Method not allowed - The method is not allowed for the requested URL.` - my python script is as follows:

Code

```py
# Define allowed file extensions
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'}

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@blueprint.route('/test1', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    message = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            message = 'No file part'
        else:
            file = request.files['file']
            if file.filename == '':
                message = 'No file selected'
            elif not allowed_file(file.filename):
                message = 'File type not allowed. Allowed types are: ' + ', '.join(ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS)
            else:
                # Save the file. In production, consider using a library or
                # service like Amazon S3, and ensure the filename is secure
                # (see Werkzeug's secure_filename)
                filepath = os.path.join('docs', file.filename)
                file.save(filepath)
                message = 'File uploaded successfully!'
    
    return render_template('test1.html', message=message)
```

Html

```html
<div class="col-lg-8 col-xlg-9 col-md-7">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h1>File Upload</h1>
            <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <p><input type="file" name="file"></p>
              <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
            </form>
            <hr>
            {% for file in files %}
              <img src="{{ url_for('/docs', filename=file) }}" style="width: 64px">
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i dont see how you handle the `GET` request to print the upload form. in any case, the error is not reproducible using your function

Comment: The error `Method not allowed ` come from when the request call method is not register. In this case is GET. Check the request call method POST to server. Client request is wrong method